# Cannot run node file in the index page

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I am new in computer science and i love programming. So I start learning nodejs and i have wrote this simple code in test.js..

```
var http = require("http");
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path');
var msg= "hi\nhow r u ?\nfine";
var file='textms.txt';
http.createServer(function (req,res){
    fs.open(file,function(exists){
        if(exists){
            fs.open(file,msg,function(err){
                if(err)throw err;   
            });
        }else{
            fs.writeFile('test.txt',msg);
            console.log('New file is created : ');
        }

    });
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);

console.log('server running on port 8080');
```

this is my index.html page code ..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Chat Test With Nodejs
        </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cnt"></div>
    <input type="text" class="text">
    <button id="btn">Send</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

i run this code on chrome(localhost:8080). it works fine.

Problem: when i run my `index.html` page on chrome, i get this error in chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined @ server.js:1
```

i tried to search on google, i didnt find anything useful.
Questions: why i am getting this error ?

Comment: Are you importing your server js script inside index.html ? Well it is not correct. You need to `run` or create a server in NodeJS and `Serve` your HTML files through it.

Comment: You're confusing  client-side Javascript and server-side Javascript.  You need to actually run Node.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are pretty new to Node. To answer your question, you don't run your server file in your index.html. Your server file is what runs your index.html.... Kinda.

Rather than going on a really long explanation about how Node works, I am going to give you this resource, [NodeSchool](http://nodeschool.io/). Probably one of the best places to start learning Node.

Good luck and if  you every have any questions, feel free to reach out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Is `server.js` the in your HTML file pointing to your Node server? If so, then your browser is trying to run a Node server (or node file) which it can't do. Also, your error seems to be that `require` is not defined, which makes perfect sense, because `require` is a Node function, not a native JS function.

Comment: `require` is a function, not a module.

Comment: My mistake. Updated to function.

Comment: how can  i create custom url like ws://localhost/echo ?please i  need help

Answer (score 1):

Dumb! :)

NodeJS is serverside javascript interpreter.
So You cannot include it in Your html code.

1. install nodejs
2. navigate to folder where server.js lies
3. and run from command prompt:

```
node server.js
```

or

```
nodejs server.js
```

and then open in Your browser: **http://127.0.0.1:8080**

p.s. go watch tutorials in Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI&index=1&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_

Comment: why every scoket have to run in  cmd ?

Comment: because there is no builtin nodejs module (like mod_php, php-fpm) for web servers like nginx, apache. so have to run it from cmd (terminal)